# installing node module via npm doesnt include all files from github repo

Tags: node.js, npm

I got a weird issue which I never experienced before and cant find a solution for this. I want to install this package with npm install but when I check its directory inside the node_modules directory, some files that are included in the github repo are not installed.

https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-js

In this case, inside the lib/resources/data folder, there is no datav2 and entityv2 file. Does anyone know why that happens?

Thanks

Comment: That's 100% on the package maintainer - there is no obligation to publish the files from the repo.  You should reach out to the package owner and ask why they aren't included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inside the lib/resources/data folder, there is no datav2 and entityv2 file

if you will look carefully within the repository, the only file within [`lib/resources/data`](https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-js/tree/master/lib/resources/data) is `bars.js`, which coincide with the package in `node_modules`

```sh
$ npm install --save @alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api
$ ls -x1 node_modules/@alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api/lib/resources/data/
bars.js
```

with that being said, if you had to the [package on npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api) you can see it was published 5 months ago.

```sh
$ npm view @alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api --json | jq '.time."1.4.2"'
"2020-10-08T19:39:11.959Z"
```

where the [files that you are after](https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-js/blob/master/lib/resources/datav2/entityv2.js), created 9 days ago

```sh
$ git log --follow --diff-filter=A --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" -- lib/resources/datav2/entityv2.js
b5919a3 noramehesz      Tue Mar 2 10:10:40 2021 +0100   Data v2 (#111)
```

> Does anyone know why that happens?

thus, the maintainer did not yet published a new version, but when the maintainer will publish a new package, it seems that the file you are after will be included

```sh
$ npm pack 2>&1 | grep lib/resources/datav2/entityv2.js
npm notice 1.0kB   lib/resources/datav2/entityv2.js
```